# Image upload via ajax POST without using HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to send some data via POST method to a PHP file without using form in HTML. This is the code I have. Why doesn't it do anything?

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Gallery_Id']; ?>" name="gid" id="gid">
<input type="hidden" value="User" name="user" id="user">
<button onclick="myFormData()">Upload Image</button>
<script>
            $('#fileToUpload').on('change', function() {
            var myFormData = new FormData();
            var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value;
            var gid = document.getElementById('gid').value;
            var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
            myFormData.append('file', file);
            myFormData.append('gid', gid);
            myFormData.append('user', user);
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: 'imgupload.php',
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false, // important
                contentType: false, // important
                dataType : 'json',
                data: myFormData
            });

            </script>
```

On `imgupload.php` I get the POST data like this

```
$gid = $_POST['gid'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

It worked when I used the HTML form method. What's wrong here?

Comment: what do you see in the console ? any errors .visit network tab

Comment: where is `myFormData()`?

Comment: you need enctype="multipart/form-data" this in form to upload files

Comment: @SantoshRamKunjir, to do this I have to use the <form> HTML tag right?

Comment: @SantoshRamKunjir, that's not what I want. If you see the question, I want to upload without using the html form. That's the whole point of this question

Comment: You're not actually pulling the values out of your input elements, you're just getting the html elements themselves.

Comment: @HeadCode, how do I do that with JS?

Comment: @YohanBlake var gid = document.getElementById('gid').value;

Comment: @HeadCode, ah yes, I had that on my code, forgot to update here. But nah, not working yet :(

Answer (score 1):

[`FormData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) takes key-value pairs, so this is wrong:

```
myFormData.append(file,gid,user);
```

You need something like:

```
myFormData.append('file', file);
myFormData.append('gid', gid);
myFormData.append('user', user);
```

Appart from that you need to put this code inside an event handler so that it triggers when you need it to.

For example:

```
$('#fileToUpload').on('change', function() {
  // your javascript code
});
```

And you should probably also put it inside a document.ready block.

Comment: I made the changes you said, but still nothing. I updated the code on the question

Comment: @YohanBlake If you missed it, see my comment below your question.

Comment: @HeadCode There is definitely plenty wrong here :-)